# Using append() on transient anonymous lists inside of a list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
mylist = [['A;B', 'C'], ['D;E', 'F']]
```

I'd like to have it in the following form:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Figured I'd write a simple list comprehension to do the task:

```
>>> newlist = [item[0].split(';').append(item[1]) for item in mylist]
>>> newlist
[None, None]
```

After some experimenting, I found that the error was in trying to use `append()` on anonymous lists:

```
>>> type(['A', 'B'])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(['A', 'B'].append('C'))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Which seems like a gotcha, considering that you can do things like this:

```
>>> 'abc'.upper()
'ABC'
```

Obviously in most cases you could get around this by binding `['A', 'B']` to a variable before calling `append()`, but how would I make this work inside of a list comprehension? Furthermore, can anyone explain this unintuitive behavior?

Comment: i don't think its unintuitive, `.append()` edits the instance it was called from and returns no values (or None)...

Comment: You can add last element to your list that you get after split(): `[item[0].split(';') + [item[1]] for item in mylist]`

Comment: @pbm: Thanks :) Every time I had previously used `+` I had forgotten to wrap `item[1]` in brackets, which led me to believe that `append()` was the correct way to proceed.

Comment: @yurib: I'd argue that it is unintuitive when compared to the given example of `'abc'.upper()`, which returns an entirely new string... although I suppose having `append()` modify the list in-place makes sense for the sake of efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, mutating methods aren't of much use inside a list comprehension because the transient objects disappear immediately.

What works instead is to build-up a list through concatenation:

```
>>> mylist = [['A;B', 'C'], ['D;E', 'F']]
>>> [first.split(';') + [second] for first, second in mylist]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[a.split(';') + [b] for a, b in mylist]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are storing the return value of the `append()` method, which is `None`.

One solution is to use `itertools.chain()` and store it in a list like so:

```
import itertools
mylist = [['A;B', 'C'], ['D;E', 'F']]
newlist = [list(itertools.chain(item[0].split(';'),item[1])) for item in mylist]
print newlist
```

prints:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Comment: Thank you, Captain Obvious. </snark>

Comment: I guess I was thinking too functionally :/

Is there a better way of achieving my original goal using list comprehensions?

Comment: I like Yak's answer better than mine as solutions go

Answer (score 0):

As Will mentioned, the result of `append()` will be `None`, and you actually want the resulting list.  Here is one option:

```
>>> mylist = [['A;B', 'C'], ['D;E', 'F']]
>>> mylist = [item[0].split(';') + [item[1]] for item in mylist]
>>> mylist
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```